# Convert Field (day , hours, mint, sec ) value in sec

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

Input: `20 day 7 hr 10 min 6 sec`

Desired output: `1753806 Sec`

How?

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
Public Function Zeconds(sIn As String) As Long
    Dim d As Long, h As Long, m As Long, s As Long
    ary = Split(sIn, " ")
    d = CLng(ary(0)) * 24 * 60 * 60
    h = CLng(ary(2)) * 60 * 60
    m = CLng(ary(4)) * 60
    s = CLng(ary(6))
    Zeconds = d + h + m + s
End Function
```